# Read Jenkins environment variables in Android project? Sign APK for automated builds

Tags: android, jenkins, environment-variables, fastlane

Thought I would find the answer through searching but no luck. I am planning on automating my build process and uploading builds to `Crashlytics Beta` via `fastlane` on my Jenkins server. `Crashlytics beta` requires signed APKS, but of course I don't want to add my `keystore` and password directly into my `build.gradle` file, and then into version control.

I was pointed in the direction of Jenkins env variables. This is what I have in my Android project:

```
signingConfigs {
   release {
        storeFile file(ANDROID_KEYSTORE)
        storePassword ANDROID_STORE_PASSWORD
        keyAlias ANDROID_KEY_ALIAS
        keyPassword ANDROID_STORE_PASSWORD
   }
}
```

Then in my `gradle.properties` file I have the following:

```
ANDROID_KEYSTORE=$ANDROID_KEYSTORE
ANDROID_STORE_PASSWORD=$ANDROID_STORE_PASSWORD
ANDROID_KEY_ALIAS=$ANDROID_KEY_ALIAS
```

When I try to build my project on `jenkins` via `fastlane`, I get the following error:

```
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:validateReleaseSigning'.
> Keystore file /Users/macmini/.jenkins/workspace/AndroidProject/app/$ANDROID_KEYSTORE not found for signing config 'release'.
```

One other thing, I have env in terminal and it showed me all the system env variables, the ones I had defined were not there, so I'm not entirely sure where `Jenkins` puts them. Do I need a direct path? What would that be?

Any help is appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Mike from Fabric and Fastlane here.

I don't believe that this:

```
ANDROID_KEYSTORE=$ANDROID_KEYSTORE
ANDROID_STORE_PASSWORD=$ANDROID_STORE_PASSWORD
ANDROID_KEY_ALIAS=$ANDROID_KEY_ALIAS
```

will work in the way you're hoping for. If you've already got the environment variables set with the values you want, you can use `String.valueOf(System.env.ANDROID_KEYSTORE)` etc. within your `build.gradle` and skip putting anything else in `gradle.properties`.

Comment: This worked with a slight tweak. I had to instead make it String.valueOf(System.env.ANDROID_KEYSTORE) otherwise my project would fail to compile with the following error: Neither path nor baseDir may be null or empty string

Answer (score 2):

Assuming your questions are: "do I need a direct (or absolute) path (to the keystore)" and "what would that (path) be".

I would answer "no" and "it's likely to be the path shown in the last line of your log, but including the expansion of the variable $ANDROID_KEYSTORE"!

In fact, I came across your question looking to achieve pretty much the same on a Jenkins GNU/Linux slave.

First, I think the problem you're facing is those environment variables will not be expanded from the gradle.properties file! Groovy is sometime magic, so I've checked to be sure: it does not do that, which explains why you got a wrong path to your keystore (containing the string "$ANDROID_KEYSTORE" rather than the value of the variable).

To fix this, I see two options:

1. You can try configuring your Jenkins job (possibly with a pre-step) to generate this gradle.properties file with the expanded values:

   echo "ANDROID_KEYSTORE=${ANDROID_KEYSTORE}" >> gradle.properties

You may even consider using a specific properties file as suggested [here](https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/app-signing.html#secure-shared-keystore).

2. A much flexible option in my opinion would be to add some code to try to read those variable from the environment and then use the properties file as described above to define the default values (useful if some developer have a copy of the key and are allow to manually release a version).

I've successfully tested something like this in app/build.gradle:

```
// Load a specific properties file to access the keystore if exists
def keystoreProperties = new Properties()
def keystorePropertiesFile = rootProject.file("keystore.properties")

if (keystorePropertiesFile.exists() ) {
    // Load keystore properties from file
    keystoreProperties.load(new FileInputStream(keystorePropertiesFile))
} else {
    // Load keystore properties from environment or set their default values
    def env = System.getenv()
    if (env['ANDROID_KEYALIAS']) keystoreProperties.put('keyAlias', env['ANDROID_KEYALIAS'])
    else keystoreProperties.put('keyAlias', "myDefaultAlias")
    if (env['ANDROID_KEYPASSWORD']) keystoreProperties.put('keyPassword', env['ANDROID_KEYPASSWORD'])
    else keystoreProperties.put('keyPassword', "myDefaultKeyPass")
    if (env['ANDROID_STOREFILE']) keystoreProperties.put('storeFile', env['ANDROID_STOREFILE'])
    else keystoreProperties.put('storeFile', "./keystore.jks")
    if (env['ANDROID_STOREPASSWORD']) keystoreProperties.put('storePassword', env['ANDROID_STOREPASSWORD'])
    else keystoreProperties.put('storePassword', "myDefaultStorePass")
}

...

android {
    signingConfigs {
        release {
            keyAlias keystoreProperties['keyAlias']
            keyPassword keystoreProperties['keyPassword']
            storeFile file(keystoreProperties['storeFile'])
            storePassword keystoreProperties['storePassword']
        }
    }
```

I'm sure this can be improved and lot, and possibly turned the way around to overwrite properties with environment variables if present. But it works for me today.

This being said, as you mentioned, if you don't see those variables in the output of the `env` command, you better look for them. I suggest you start your build step using that `env` command. For sure, typing this command in a seperate terminal will not show you what Jenkins is doing for that specific build.